# Publish app in Google play store when migrating from expo to bare react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I had developed an app using Expo and published it in Google Play Store. It was running fine till now. But now I have a requirement to add a payment gateway. As of now, only stripe is available in expo. I wanted to add Razorpay Payment Gateway in the app.

So, I tried to eject the app and worked on it. But there were certain issues while building apk file. Then I tried to create a bare react native app from scratch and eventually I completed the work.

Now I want to publish the app in google app store.

If I create new keystore credential and upload it in Play store, will it work or I will have to use same keystore credentials that i used using expo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same keystore and applicationId. The versionCode of the new app needs to be higher than the existing versionCode.

Comment: I tried this too but failing constantly. I guess I am entering wrong keystore password. Is there anyway to reset the keystore password or replace the existing keystore credentials with new one?

Comment: There is no way to change the keystore without knowing the password.

Comment: What are u mean ab keystore ? I tried to publish my app so now I'm trying to update the app but I had this error in second release Your Android App Bundle was signed with the wrong key. Make sure your app bundle is signed with the correct key and try again. The app bundle you uploaded should normally be signed with the certificate associated with the thumbprint

Comment: @Kindth https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Apps need to be signed with a signig key that are stored in a keystore file. They are protected by a password. You need to make sure that you use the same signing key and password for each update of your app. Otherwise you are screwed.